# Wordpress Post Table aligment

Tags: html, css, wordpress

for few days I'm trying to set up an easy table.
I have tested almost everything and i'm at the end of the rope.

Table with vertical-align: baseline;
http://loredores.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/s1.png

Table without vertical-align: baseline;
http://loredores.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/s2.png

Now I am looking where should I place vertical-align and which type to get the result as at s2 page.

Sita http://loredores.com/uslugi/facility-management/

Comment: clear your questions you want to show table like image s2 and want to know where should place the css?

Comment: I tried to place it almost everywhere for few Horus. I ended on  Theme style is forcing to Change my style in The post. I know The question looks "do it for me" but i have tried almost everything for 5 hours nad i am desperated :( My goal is to set table as on pic2

Comment: did you tried to add code into theme customize custom css options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all goto your theme directory style.css the path of theme directory style.css is this `http://loredores.com/wp-content/themes/spacious-pro/style.css`

Then find the css rule

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

and replace it with

```
/*vertical-align: baseline;*/
```

check screenshot : [image]

or you can remove it and it will be fine like this

https://prnt.sc/hh3zvx

Thanks

Comment: Working perfect! Rest of site look also good :)
Now I'am wondering WHY i missed it ;)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code to styles.css. hope this will fix the issue

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle!important;
}
```